# En mi aplicacion en la nube no funcionan mis endpoint de forma correcta, sin embargo en mi localhost si

Tags: javascript, java, hosting, cors, error404

estoy trabajando en una pagina web, utilizando react + js en el front, y java + springboot en el backend.
Cuando testeo la app, todo funciona de forma correcta, mi problema fue cuando subi todo al hosting.
Un problema que tengo, es que las rutas funcionan, solo si llego a ellas mediante eventos: por ejemplo, si quiero registrarme y voy directamente a mipagina.com.ar/register encuentro este error:
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
En la consola de navegador:
register:1 GET https://mipagina.com.ar/register 404 (Not Found)
Request URL:
https://mipagina.com.ar/register
Request Method:
GET
Status Code:
404 Not Found
Remote Address:
104.156.62.240:443
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Ahora, si llego a la URL clickeando en el boton "Registrarse" esto funciona de forma correcta.
Una vez que estoy en mi register, e intento rregistrarme tengo el siguiente problema:
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/customer/addCustomer' from origin 'https://mipagina.com.ar' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
index-4469abf9.js:69 POST http://localhost:8080/customer/addCustomer net::ERR_FAILED

Lo que no entiendo, es la razon de que aparece localhost:8080 y no la url de mi pagina.
En mi backend tengo este bean configuration:

```
    @Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("*")); // Esto permite que cualquier origen acceda.
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH"));
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

Y este es mi peticion en mi archivo register:

```
const handleRegisterUser = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (name && lastname && address && phone && email && password) {
        setError(false);
        axios
            .post('https://mipagina.com.ar/customer/addCustomer', {
                name: name,
                lastName: lastname,
                address: address,
                contactNumber: Number(phone),
                email: email,
                password: password,
                pets: petsArray,
            })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log("respuesta:", response);
                if (response.status === 200 || response.status === 201) {
                    setDataUser(response.config.data);
                    setName("");
                    setLastname("");
                    setAddress("");
                    setPhone("");
                    setEmail("");
                    setPassword("");
                    goBack();
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => console.log("esta cayendo en este error",error));
    } else {
        setError(true);
        setErrorRegisterMsj("Debes completar todos los campos del formulario");
    }
```